# Calling API data in Blazor WebAssembly in .NET 6.0

Tags: .net, rest, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, webassembly

I have `tblmenu` model

```
public class TblMenus
{
    public int menuID { get; set; }
    public string menuTitle { get; set; }
    public int menuINDEX { get; set; }
    public bool menuAcitve { get; set; }
    public int menuLevel { get; set; }
    public int menuGroupID { get; set; }
    public string menuURL { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get data from using REST API but failed to get data.
I have used the following method:

```
public async  Task<IEnumerable<TblMenus>>Getoutput()
{
   
    //https://liveexshield.com/apiBLZ/api/GETData/2,a,a
     return await 
     httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<TblMenus[]>"apiBLZ/api/GETData/2,a,a");
  
}
```

but when I use another API to get data same method works fine but in this case my API is working.

Comment: Your model may be wrong? Is this property correct?  `public bool menuAcitve { get; set; }`  **Acitve**.  Also try this: `httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<TblMenus>>`

Comment: yes its has it work fine on Blazor Server Side. is there any method, pattern difference or setting on program.cs file  issue on client side

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.